# Do bigger aircraft make a bigger sonic boom?

Tags: supersonic

I was watching an episode of [MythBusters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MythBusters_%282009_season%29#Sonic_Boom_Sound-off) where they were trying to break glass windows and cups using a sonic boom generated by a [F/A-18 Hornet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_F/A-18_Hornet), flown by the [Blue Angels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Angels).  In summary, they were unsuccessful at creating a boom that could shatter the windows, despite a mach speed pass within 200ft of the target building. In the last two passes they even flew straight at the building to focus the boom straight at the house, still no windows were shattered. **

But I've wondered, ever since, if they were unsuccessful because the plane was simply too small.  What if the sonic boom had been generated by a [B-1 Lancer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rockwell_B-1_Lancer) or perhaps Concorde, which are several times larger than the F/A-18?  Logically it seems that since you are displacing more air, the energy wave should have more energy.  Then again, the plane isn't going any faster, so perhaps the surface area of the wave would be larger (because of the larger plane) but you wouldn't actually have any more energy at any given point?

Anyone know if a bigger plan than the F/A-18 would have a higher energy sonic boom?  And could that cause glass to break?

Bonus point:
A mathematical formula showing why, I love those things.

*For those curious about what a sonic boom is to begin with, here's a [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_boom)*.

**Just to clarify, for those who have seen the episode.  A window *is* broken during the 200ft pass but they say that it only happened because the frame warped, not because the glass itself shattered.  Their reasoning is that only that one window broke (out of several windows and glass cups in the area), and it had a pretty cheap frame on it.

Comment: I don't know for sure the relationship, but I found this: `The strongest sonic boom ever recorded was 7,000 Pa (144 psf) and it did not cause injury to the researchers who were exposed to it. The boom was produced by an F-4 flying just above the speed of sound at an altitude of 100 feet (30 m)`

Comment: And [here](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc01/professional/papers/pap284/p284.htm) is some really good information

Comment: @SSummer - Thanks, it looks like that got spun into a full answer below.  Reading that makes me wonder how much overpressure that F/A-18 was producing at 200ft...  They don't really say in the show.

Comment: It would have been hard to use a Concorde for that episode, given that the last ones had been grounded in 2003, six years previously.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The short version is that yes, larger aircraft create bigger sonic booms, but you still have to be flying very low (less than 100 ft.) and really trying hard in order to damage glass.

A sonic boom is so complicated that you will not find a simple formula to determine the strength.  [This article](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc01/professional/papers/pap284/p284.htm) describes a modeling tool called PCBoom3 which can be used for sonic boom calculations.

---

According to several different sites, like [this one](http://www.alamogordoforum.com/sonic_booms.htm) and [this one](http://library.thinkquest.org/12228/Page3.html), the size of the aircraft does affect the intensity:

> ## Factors Affecting Sonic Boom Intensity
>
> The intensity of sonic booms are affected by:
>
> - Weight, size and shape of the aircraft.
> - Altitude
> - Attitude—orientation of the aircraft’s axes relative to the its direction of motion.
> - Flight path.
> - Atmospheric and weather conditions.
>
> As the size and weight of the aircraft increases, the intensity of the
>   sonic increases. This is because a larger aircraft displaces more air,
>   and a heavier aircraft needs a greater force of lift to sustain
>   flight. Thus creating a louder and stronger sonic boom.

and

> ## General Factors Associated With Sonic Booms
>
> There are several factors
>   that can influence sonic booms -- weight, size, and shape of the
>   aircraft or vehicle, plus its altitude, attitude and flight path, and
>   weather or atmospheric conditions.
>
> A larger and heavier aircraft must displace more air and create more
>   lift to sustain flight, compared with small, light aircraft.
>   Therefore, they will create sonic booms stronger and louder than those
>   of smaller, lighter aircraft. The larger and heavier the aircraft, the
>   stronger the shock waves will be.

[NASA](http://www.nasa.gov/centers/dryden/Features/WSPR_research_complete.html#.Uyz1t61dXuE) says that a typical sonic boom for the F/A-18 is about 1.4 psf and a [different NASA page](http://www.nasa.gov/centers/armstrong/news/FactSheets/FS-016-DFRC.html#.Uyz2TK1dXuE) goes on to say:

> Overpressure Sonic booms are measured in pounds per square foot of
>   overpressure. This is the amount of the increase over the normal
>   atmospheric pressure which surrounds us (2,116 psf/14.7 psi).  At one
>   pound overpressure, no damage to structures would be expected.
>   Overpressures of 1 to 2 pounds are produced by supersonic aircraft
>   flying at normal operating altitudes. Some public reaction could be
>   expected between 1.5 and 2 lb.  Rare minor damage may occur with 2 to
>   5 lb overpressure.
>
> As overpressure increases, the likelihood of structural damage and
>   stronger public reaction also increases. Tests, however, have shown
>   that structures in good condition have been undamaged by overpressures
>   of up to 11 lb.  Sonic booms produced by aircraft flying supersonic at
>   altitudes of less than 100 feet, creating between 20 and 144 lb
>   overpressure, have been experienced by humans without injury.
>
> Damage to eardrums can be expected when overpressures reach 720 lb.
>   Overpressures of 2160 lb would have to be generated to produce lung
>   damage.
>
> Typical overpressure of aircraft types are:
>
> - SR-71: 0.9 lb, speed of Mach 3, 80,000 feet
> - Concorde SST: 1.94 lb, speed of Mach 2, 52,000 feet
> - F-104: 0.8 lb, speed of Mach 1.93, 48,000 feet
> - Space Shuttle: 1.25 lb, speed of Mach 1.5, 60,000 feet, landing approach

They also include a graphic that shows the difference in sonic boom between the F-18 and the Concorde, with the Concorde having a much greater sonic boom at the same alittude:

[image: Sonic Boom Plots]

---

[This article](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/684806.pdf) specifically covers glass:

> **Glass**. Poorly mounted, undamaged glass in the greenhouse was chipped
>   by impact against nail holding points at a sonic boom overpressure of
>   12.1 psf. The same type of glass, which was already damaged, was further damaged at a designed overpressure of 7.9 psf. A large
>   one-ninth of an inch thick window, intentionally precracked from
>   corner to corner, was further damaged by booms of an average 6.5 psf
>   overpressure.

So typical sonic booms generated by normal aircraft aren't going to create anywhere close to the 12.1 psf that they say is needed to chip "poorly mounted" glass, but the strongest sonic booms can get well over this.

Comment: Sounds to me like they should have tried a pass at about 50ft...  If such a thing were legal.  Though it would be interesting to see if perhaps a B1, at the same speed and altitude, would have created enough over-pressure to break the glasses that were sitting on the table in that episode.

Comment: Fantastic, great answer, yet again :).